# Absolute viewport for messi pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

Suppose, I have a web page which consists table of item long enough to use a scroll bar to move up and down the page.
So, when I am trying to use messi pop up in it with default viewport and clicking on item which results into opening of a messi pop-up.

The problem is:
On keeping default viewport, pop up always appears in middle of the web page irrespective of where it is clicked. What  viewport should I set, so that I always get my popup in middle of the screen of my laptop, not in middle of the whole web page.

Link to messi pop up web page is [here](http://marcosesperon.es/apps/messi/)

Answer (score 0):

used jquery .position() to set the viewport to dynamic. It was not an messi popup specific issue. it was a general issue.